# How can i open a group of ports in ASA 5512?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, security

Am dealing ASA first time.

I want to install aplplication in my server and it needs some ports to be open in firewall.
so i  need to open tcp,udp,http,https,ssl ports.
How can i configure this on Cisco ASA 5512?

Edit:

am going to place the server inside.

i have this access list in my firewall

```
access-list broadband extended permit ip X.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 any
```

I need to update the application from outside.

Comment: We need a little more information.  Where is the server in relation to the firewall?  Are you opening ports from the outside?  Please edit your post to include the firewall configuration.

Comment: OK, HTTP is TCP port 80, HTTPS is TCP port 443... but we also need to know what port you're using for SSL (is it TCP port 22 for SSH and SFTP?), and which TCP and UDP ports you want allowed. I'm assuming (maybe unfairly?) that you would like something more specific than just permitting any IP traffic from the outside world to your network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure Access Rules.  Below is an example to get you started.  You need to build yours to suit your needs.

```
hostname(config)# access-list outside_access extended permit tcp any object inside-server1 eq www
hostname(config)# access-group outside_access in interface outside
```

[CLI Book 2: Cisco ASA Series Firewall CLI Configuration Guide, 9.6](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa96/configuration/firewall/asa-96-firewall-config/access-rules.html#ID-2124-00000004)

**Controlling Network Access**
Access rules determine which traffic is allowed through the ASA. There are several different layers of rules that work together to implement your access control policy:

- Extended access rules (Layer 3+ traffic) assigned to interfaces—You
  can apply separate rule sets (ACLs) in the inbound and outbound
  directions. An extended access rule permits or denies traffic based
  on the source and destination traffic criteria.
- Extended access rules assigned globally—You can create a single
  global rule set, which serves as your default access control. The
  global rules are applied after interface rules.
- Management access rules (Layer 3+ traffic)—You can apply a single
  rule set to cover traffic directed at an interface, which would
  typically be management traffic. In the CLI, these are “control
  plane” access groups. For ICMP traffic directed at the device, you
  can alternatively configure ICMP rules.

Comment: Since @Tech is new to using ASAs he may also need to know it is necessary to create the appropriate NAT rules in addition to making ACLs to allow the traffic to the server. Depending on his ASA version number the NAT statements may need to point to the private IP address of the server or the public IP address before it is translated to the private IP address of the server.